# Creating a local variable in an if statement?

Tags: solidity, ether, solidity-0.8.x, function, code

I'm looking at a function that creates a local variable in an if statement. If someone called that function and the condition to the if statement was not triggered, that local variable wouldn't exist, right?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It's like other languages it won't exist in out of the scope.
solc compiler give you `Undeclared identifier` error.
for example

```
if (everything) {
   uint testVariable = 1;
}
require(testVariable == 1, "error"); // you will have Undeclared identifier error in here
```